# Struct variable is set but not used even though I use it immediately

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, struct

I am working on a class project that involves simulating a level 1 cache. The project is being done in c++, which I am still not super comfortable with. For the simulator, we need to have a struct to represent the tag array, which I have created within a `cache` class. I also have a struct of type `tag` that has different members. I believe I have properly set up the `tag_array` struct to allow for the creation of a dynamically sized array of `tag` structs, but I could be wrong.

My issue arises when attempting to create this array and initialize the tag's members to 0. I create an instance of the tag struct called entry and then try to set its members equal to zero, but when I compile, I get the error `"warning: variable ‘entry’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]"`I've included most of the relevant code but please ask for more if I have failed to include something necessary.

cache.h

```
class cache{

//other code and variables

// Tag Array
    typedef struct {
        unsigned valid_bit;
        unsigned index;
        unsigned dirty_bit;
        char* tag;      
    }tag_t;

    typedef struct {
        unsigned num_entries;
        tag_t *entries;
    }tag_array;

    tag_array cache_tag_array;

//other variables and functions
```

cache.cc

```
cache::cache(unsigned size, 
      unsigned associativity,
      unsigned line_size,
      write_policy_t wr_hit_policy,
      write_policy_t wr_miss_policy,
      unsigned hit_time,
      unsigned miss_penalty,
      unsigned address_width
){
    cache_size = size;
    cache_associativity = associativity;
    cache_line_size = line_size;
    cache_write_hit_policy = wr_hit_policy;
    cache_write_miss_policy = wr_miss_policy;
    cache_hit_time = hit_time;
    cache_miss_penalty = miss_penalty;
    cache_address_width = address_width;
    cache_num_blocks = size / line_size;
    cache_num_sets = size / (line_size * associativity);
    cache_tag_array.num_entries = cache_num_blocks;
    tag_bits = address_width - log2(cache_num_sets) - log2(cache_line_size);
    current_access.block_offset = 0;
    current_access.index = 0;
    cache::cache_tag_array.entries = new cache::tag_t[cache_num_blocks];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < cache_tag_array.num_entries; i++)
    {
        cache::tag_t entry = cache_tag_array.entries[i];
        entry.valid_bit = 0;
        entry.index = 0;
        entry.dirty_bit = 0;
        entry.tag = {};
    }
}
```

I believe the issue arises from this block

```
cache::cache_tag_array.entries = new cache::tag_t[cache_num_blocks];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < cache_tag_array.num_entries; i++)
    {
        cache::tag_t entry = cache_tag_array.entries[i];
        entry.valid_bit = 0;
        entry.index = 0;
        entry.dirty_bit = 0;
        entry.tag = {};
    }
```

but I could be mistaken.

All variables used in the constructor class are public members of the cache class and I know I am able to change their values, but I cannot get there to be any entries in my tag array. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*This question is not a major part of the assignment I'm asking for help on, just a c++ issue I don't know what to do with. The real challenge of the simulator is updating this tag array properly for read and write hits and misses.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error is that you are assigning to a local variable but doing nothing with that variable. It's clear that you expect in

```
cache::tag_t entry = cache_tag_array.entries[i];
```

that `entry` is some sort of alias for `cache_tag_array.entries[i]` but it isn't. It's a completely separate variable and assigning to `entry` has no effect on `cache_tag_array.entries[i]`.

The code you want is almost the same

```
cache::tag_t& entry = cache_tag_array.entries[i];
```

but that `&` makes all the difference. Now `entry` is a reference which refers to `cache_tag_array.entries[i]` not a separate variable.